# Docker: Change word in file at container startup

Tags: docker, fluentd

I'm creating a docker image for our fluentd.
The image contains a file called http_forward.conf
It contains:

```
<store>
   type http
   endpoint_url    ENDPOINTPLACEHOLDER
   http_method     post    # default: post
   serializer      json   # default: form
   rate_limit_msec 100    # default: 0 = no rate limiting
   raise_on_error  true  # default: true
   authentication  none  # default: none
   username        xxx  # default: ''
   password        xxx # default: '', secret: true
</store>
```

So this is in our image. But we want to use the image for all our environments. Specified with environment variables.

So we create an environment variable for our environment:

```
ISSUE_SERVICE_URL = http://xxx.dev.xxx.xx/api/fluentdIssue
```

This env variable contains dev on our dev environment, uat on uat etc.
Than we want to replace our ENDPOINTPLACEHOLDER with the value of our env variable. In bash we can use:

```
sed -i -- 's/ENDPOINTPLACEHOLDER/'"$ISSUE_SERVICE_URL"'/g' .../http_forward.conf
```

But how/when do we have to execute this command if we want to use this in our docker container? (we don't want to mount this file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your DockerFile you should have a line starting with CMD somewhere. You should add it there.

Or you can do it cleaner: set the CMD line to call a script instead. For example `CMD ./startup.sh`. The file startup.sh will then contain your sed command followed by the command to start your fluentd (I assume that is currently the CMD).

Answer (score 1):

We did that via `ansible` coding.

Put the file `http_forward.conf` as template, and deploy the change depend on the environment, then mount the folder (include the conf file) to docker container.

```
ISSUE_SERVICE_URL = http://xxx.{{ environment }}.xxx.xx/api/fluentdIssue
```

playbook will be something like this, I don't test it.

```
- template: src=http_forward.conf.j2 dest=/config/http_forward.conf mode=0644

- docker:
      name: "fluentd"
      image: "xxx/fluentd"
      restart_policy: always
      volumes:
        - /config:/etc/fluent
```

Comment: nice solution, I'll upvote but I try to find a way without helptools